# Flask SQLalchemy Many-to-Many: select and update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'am totally new to SQLAlchemy and your help is greatly appreciated.

I have those 2 models with many to many relation:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    tags = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)

class Collection(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

    items = db.relationship('Item', secondary=sets, lazy='subquery')


sets = db.Table( 'sets',
    db.Column('item_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('item.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('collection_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('collection.id'), primary_key=True)
    db.Column('rating', db.Integer, nullable=True),
    db.Column('status', db.Integer, nullable=True)
)
```

And I'm trying to select items:

```
WHERE collection_id = 100
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 30
```

And after some operations with these items I also need to update their `status`. How it can be done in proper way?

For select I guess it's something like

```
db.session.query(Collection.items).filter_by(collection=100).order_by(rating.desc())
```

Thank you!

Comment: For a standard many-to-many in sqlalchemy, the relationship only cares about the foreign key columns in the secondary table, and it is transparent to the user. For the case where your secondary table holds more info than that the standard pattern is to use an [association object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object). Have you come across that part of the docs?

Comment: (to SuperShoot) I haven't yet, thank you